# Is there some kind of Exchange 2007 API?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

We have a Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 running. We manage several contacts inside of the public contacts we access via Outlook Clients.

We have some Information of Contacts in separate MySQL databases.

I was wondering if some kind of API exists (from Microsoft Exchange) to transfer Information from those MySQL databases or any other source into the exchange "data store".

Comment: Transfer info the mail store? I highly doubt it.

Comment: You could probably craft a PowerShell script to synchronize the data. There's plenty of Ex PS examples out there, and I'd be reasonably sure there's a MySQL ODBC that PS can use as well. It would be nasty complicated however, and I've not head of such a script before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be the Exchange Managed Web Services API.  It's .NET based but you could easily use it via PowerShell as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749(v=EXCHG.80).aspx